# Database engine to work under OS X and Windows

Tags: database, windows, macos, operating-system

I'm about to write an app that should work under OS X and Windows XP/Vista/7. The app will require a database engine. Can someone suggest one that can do the following:

1. Be compatible with Windows
2. Be compatible with OS X (and preferably with iOS)
3. Preferably be available by default in those operating systems, or require minimum installation.

I understand that all three items may be hard to come by. So just curious, whatever is available?

Comment: For future reference, [X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System#The_X.Org_Foundation) and Mac OS X are different.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still struggling to figure out how this site works....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My favorite is Sql Lite: http://sqlite.org/

It requires no installation, and is a small binary.

Comment: Probably the best suggestion.

Comment: Also, you technically don't need a separate binary at all, since you can statically link it into your program, or even compile in the C file (called an [amalgamation](http://www.sqlite.org/amalgamation.html)).  However, the shared library usually works fine.

Comment: Wow, that is awesome, fellas!!! Thanks a lot. I hope it can handle big databases as well...